# Python Pillow EXIF data not returning

Tags: python, python-2.7, exif, python-imaging-library

I'm using some sample code trying to return the exif information from a sample .jpg image. The Python code is:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS

def get_exif(fn):
  ret = {}
  i = Image.open('C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Sample1.jpg')
  info = i._getexif()
  for tag, value in info.items():
    decoded = TAGS.get(tag, tag)
    ret[decoded] = value
  return ret
```

The code runs with no error, but doesn't output anything. Also, tried to output it to a file, but couldn't write any info out either. Can someone spot why this isn't returning anything? Thank you!

Comment: Why did you do `TAGS.get(tag, tag)` ? It seems you don't know what you are doing. Are you sure your image contains Exif data ?

Comment: It does have exif data. I've check in Windows. This code is a sample code that I've found. They said it worked, which is why I'm wondering why it doesn't give errors...but doesn't return anything at all.

Comment: Your code is a function, do you call this function with get_exif() ? (I don't know why your function has an ` fn` argument since you aren't using it)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what you are trying to do but this code works for me (from python 2.7 and 3 onwards) :

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS

def get_exif():
  i = Image.open('/path/to/imagefile.jpg')
  info = i._getexif()
  return {TAGS.get(tag): value for tag, value in info.items()}

print get_exif()
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it suits you. Thanks

Comment: thanks, it works. I tried everything, i was literally no able to reading exif data until your answer.